# Get custom posts and normal posts from a category

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display custom posts 'events' and posts under category ID=8 from normal posts.

This code isn't working as it takes all normal posts. `category => 8` is not taken into account.

```
$type = array('events','post');
$args=array(
    'post_type' => $type,
    'category' => '8',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    //do stuff
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `'category' => '8'` to `'cat' => 8`.

The reason for this is that basically "cat" will accept category IDs, while "category" will accept category slugs.

For more information, you can refer to the following link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't work. It does not get any post with cat, not even the events

Comment: I've just tested the code with "cat" and it seems to work properly. You need to make sure that the ID 8 is correct, and that your taxonomy is "category". If you're trying to query another taxonomy, "cat" will not work.

Comment: Sorry, it takes only the posts in cat 8 this way and it does not take events custom posts, a solution will be to put the custom posts in that category too, but can it be done without doing that? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it can be done. However, i will need some more information from you. It appears that "events" are using a different taxonomy (not "category"). In order to find out what taxonomy are they using, go to Events -> Categories (or whatever it is in your installation), and copy the URL after /wp-admin here. I will inspect it and will provide you with additional info.

Comment: events are a custom post type `wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=events` I registered them in `function.php`

Comment: I understand about events. But under Events, do you have Categories of some sort? If yes, copy the URL of the Categories page under the Events menu item.

Comment: `wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category&post_type=eveniment` Here it is. I did not make any category specific for Events

Comment: It appears your post type is "eveniment" and not "events", so you might want to correct this in the wp_query args.